# Как узнать есть ли кириллица в массиве char*?

Tags: c++, c, char

Как можно проверить есть ли в массиве char* буквы кириллицы? Я знаю, что signed char 128, при считывании я не могу изменить тип хранить в unsigned char*.

В кодировке utf8 или какой либо другой, главное чтобы можно было различать английские и русские буквы и цифры

Пробовал делать так и все равно выходил результат 0

```
char* arra_char = "Система_из_двух_уравнений" ;
char ch = *arra_char ;
isalpha( (unsigned char) (ch) );
```

Comment: Для начала вам надо определиться в какой **кодировке** вы ищете кириллицу

Comment: @avp  можно в utf8

Comment: `isalpha` обычно как раз русский не понимает... И говорит 0 - потому что это не является буквой английского алфавита.

Comment: Символы кириллицы в utf-8 будут занимать по 2 байта. Первый из них будет 0xd0 - 0xd3 (т.е. отрицательным  в случае signed char (у вас почти наверняка это так)). Второй (а также и первый) см. в  [таблице](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1024) (ищется по запросу `cyrillic utf-8`)

Comment: Тупой, но работающий способ - загоните в той однобайтной кодировке, в которой вы собираетесь работать, строку русского алфавита, и проверяйте, есть ли в ней искомый символ...

Comment: В любой кодировке заготовьте строки из русских букв. Одна буква - одна строка. Если любая из этих заготовок встречается в тексте, это русская буква.

Comment: @kaliarty, т.е. формально любая пара байт в utf-8 где первый 0xd0 - 0xd3, а второй 0x80 - 0xbf это символ кириллицы (но я бы отмел, наверное, половину из них -))

Comment: @avp как сравнить кодировку с элементов из char* ? –

Comment: Если не заморачиваться проверкой валидности utf-8 во всей строке, то `int is_cyr_sym (char *str) { if (*str) { unsigned char c1 = *str, c2 = str[1]; if (c1 >= 0xd0 && c1 <= 0xd3 && c2 >= 0x80 && c2 <= 0xbf) return 1; /* cyrillic character */ } return 0;}`

Comment: @Harry `iswalpha()` есть. После `mbsrtowcs()` должно сработать.